# cant get data entered into comments box, using username

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i believe i have made the relevant changes to get my code to post into the comments box, but it still doesn't seem to post anything at all. Can anyone see any errors i have left in the code?

```
<form action="" method="post" >
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment">
Please type a comment if you are logged in....


</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO comment (username, comment, dCpuID) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '1')";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert)){

      header("Location: i5-6600k");
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sqlinsert. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
```

There is a session start at the very top of this doc, so it is included. The whole code is within the PHP tag.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
```

Changed this to login_user. Now seem to be some kind of DB connection but now there is an error displayed above the comment box without even submitting any comment:
ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO comment (username, comment, dCpuID) VALUES ('dan', '', '1'). Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'

```
$sql  = "SELECT `users`.`username`, `comment`.`comment`, `comment`.`timestamp`\n"

    . "FROM `users`\n"

    . "LEFT JOIN `comment` ON `users`.`userID` = `comment`.`userID` \n"

    . "where dCpuID = 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>Username</th><th>Comment</th><th>Timestamp</th>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["username"]. "</td><td>" . $row["comment"]."</td><td>"  . $row["timestamp"]. "</td>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}
```

The code above displays the comment box as i want it.

If userID instead of username (which makes a lot more sense as it is in table) this is displyed is entered it will display:

```
ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO comment (userID, comment, dCpuID) VALUES ('dan', '', '1'). Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`u803621131_login`.`comment`, CONSTRAINT `comment_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `users` (`userID`))
```

Which normally to fix means deleting tables, which somehow fixes a lot of issues, but causes more as i have to repopulate them.

Comment: Show what you have tried, and how it's gone wrong for you. This site is for answering specific questions, not writing code.

Comment: I assume that a user has logged in, and that you have stored something in `$_SESSION` to that effect. (a) _What_ have you stored there? (b) If the user has logged in, why do you want to display the user name on every row? (c) Have you included a filter for the user in the SQL?

Comment: Apropos your SQL statement: (a) you don’t need the back-tick around the names of the tables or columns if the names are normal and well-behaved, as they are; you only need them around awkward names, such as keywords, or names with spaces. (b) PHP does not require you to separate a multi-line string the way you have: if you have a new line in the middle of a string, it will be part of the string; JavaScript, on the other hand would require that in its traditional strings, but this is not JavaScript.

Comment: <?php
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['comment']);

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO comment (username, comment, dCpuID) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '1')";

$resultinsert = $conn->query($sqlinsert);

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert)){

         echo "entered comment" . mysqli_error($conn);

    } else{

        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);

    }

     

    // close connection

    mysqli_close($conn);

Comment: That is the attempted code in there (sorry about awkward positioning in here, couldnt work out how to get the main editor up..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to get data that was stored to a session, you need to session_start() at the top of the script.  You also have to have a session_start() anytime you use sessions.

In your code, you have things reversed.  You are attempting to assign a non-initialized variable to your session rather than the other way around.  I would expect something like this:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO comment (username, comment, dCpuID) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '1')";
    // etc.
} else {
    // There was no username in session.
}
```

There is no reason to store the session variable to another variable, but I included it to illustrate your mistake.  You have:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

Bonus points:  you should be using [bind parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) rather than interpolating the values into the sql statement directly.  With parameter binding you don't have to escape the comment with mysqli_real_escape_string either.

Your error message is also messed up.  Rather than:

```
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
```

You should be including the actual variable name you used:

```
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sqlinsert . " . mysqli_error($conn);
```

Comment: There is a session start at the top, just not included in this bit, i will give that other bit a try and let you know, thanks :)

Comment: I have 2 different queries on the same pagew, one being the comments display, the other the indert function, doesn't seem to be working, is that in issue? they both have different query variables, one being sqlinsert the other just sql.

Comment: If you don't provide the actual code, and the actual diagnostics, it's impossible to help you debug.  I pointed out several obvious errors in your code.  If you have more errors than that I can't diagnose them from code you didn't provide.

Comment: Also in the insert query i have excluded the commentID (auto inc) and excluded the timestamp, im assuming that should enter automatically anyway

Comment: correct, auto_increments should not be included in the list of columns or you can include them and set the value to NULL I believe.  Timestamps have the same basic property.  Regardless, if you have a mysql error, then the actual error and sql statement should be provided.  With that said, you should be using bound parameters as I noted.

Comment: So many things seem to be missing. Here's something obvious:  <textarea rows="4" cols="50">  You need a name="comment" parameter if you hope to get $_POST['comment'].    If you are self-posting to this single script you need an if -then-else where you check if the request method is POST, and you should check for a comment before you do the INSERT code.

Comment: Ive added in a similar else from my send_reg page and seems to be lots of issues still, you have pointed out lots of problems i have completely missed, i believe they are corrected, but been sat here for about 12hours and making a lot more silly mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Note that `LEFT JOIN x.... WHERE x =...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

If you want to maintain an OUTER JOIN, you can write it as follows:

```
"
SELECT u.username
     , c.comment
     , c.timestamp
  FROM users u
  LEFT 
  JOIN comment c
    ON c.userID = u.userID
   AND c.dCpuID = 1;
";
```